# ABP - Disable Auditing for a specific method of the LogInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am currently developing a backend with ABP (AspNetBoilerplate) AspNetCore 3.6.2 and Entity framework

I want to know if it is possible to prevent the modification of the LastModifierUserTime and LastModifierUserId of an AbpUser for a specific method.
I guess these properties are modified by ABP Auditing because the method LoginAsync() modifies the User entity. I am just trying to know how to disable the Audit in a scope or for a method.

```
private async Task<AbpLoginResult<Tenant, User>> GetLoginResultAsync(string usernameOrEmailAddress, string password, string tenancyName)
{
    // Some code here
    if (tenant != null)
    {
        // TODO: Cancel auditing for this method
        loginResult = await _logInManager.LoginAsync(usernameOrEmailAddress, password, tenant.TenancyName);
    }
    // Some code here
}
```

Everytime I try to log in by calling this method in my service, the user entity is modified:

1. the LastModifierUserId is set to null
2. the LastModifierUserTime is set to now

I tried to put the [DisableAuditing] attribute on the GetLoginResultAsync method but it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Using `[DisableAuditing]` attribute won't help you to prevent the setting of `LastModifierUserId` & `LastModifierUserTime` properties. These two attributes are set through EF interceptors and `EntityAuditingHelper` class. You can take a look at the source [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/552c0240c44d9899c1209fb20eb48d35b17d5e54/src/Abp/Domain/Entities/Auditing/EntityAuditingHelper.cs)

While these properties are automatically set you can consider this as LastLoginTime property. Hopefully, according to its opensource policy you can find the internal procedure at their repository [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/386c516fc7705ec388e572667826a762748ee810/src/Abp.Zero/Authorization/AbpLoginManager.cs)

All in all, if you need to disable it, you need to overrride `LoginAsync` method in `LogInManager` and simply ignore setting those properties. All repositories are injected in the constructor so you might probably need nothing to be injected as a dependency.

```
public class LogInManager : AbpLogInManager<Tenant, Role, User>
    {
        public LogInManager(
            UserManager userManager, 
            IMultiTenancyConfig multiTenancyConfig,
            IRepository<Tenant> tenantRepository,
            IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager,
            ISettingManager settingManager, 
            IRepository<UserLoginAttempt, long> userLoginAttemptRepository, 
            IUserManagementConfig userManagementConfig,
            IIocResolver iocResolver,
            IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher, 
            RoleManager roleManager,
            UserClaimsPrincipalFactory claimsPrincipalFactory) 
            : base(
                  userManager, 
                  multiTenancyConfig,
                  tenantRepository, 
                  unitOfWorkManager, 
                  settingManager, 
                  userLoginAttemptRepository, 
                  userManagementConfig, 
                  iocResolver, 
                  passwordHasher, 
                  roleManager, 
                  claimsPrincipalFactory)
        {
        }

        public override Task<AbpLoginResult<Tenant, User>> LoginAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword, string tenancyName = null, bool shouldLockout = true)
        {
            //Here you can comment this line below and write your own code !
            return base.LoginAsync(userNameOrEmailAddress, plainPassword, tenancyName, shouldLockout);
        }
    }
```